# Why isn't the ? in a regular expression working?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to parse data that would appear in a course catalog using perl, but I am struggling with getting my regular expression to work correctly.

A few sample lines of data are below:

```
Course description goes here; There might be more text; 3 hours of lecture, 2 hours of laboratory. Prerequisite: None
Another course description is here; 3 hours of lecture and laboratory. Prerequisite: None
More description; 4 hours of laboratory. Prerequisite: None
```

I wanted to capture the full description (everything before the final semicolon), then the hours (and later I would handle what hour matches up with lecture or lab). The regular expression I was trying to use was this:

```
/^(.*)\; *([0-9]).*?(lecture|laboratory).*?([0-9])?.*$/
```

It seems to work up until `([0-9])?`. I thought this would match the second hour number (if there was one), and then the `.*` after it would match the rest of the line, but this isn't the case. Instead, the final `.*` matches the second hour and everything after it too.

Why doesn't the use of the `?` match the second hour if it is there. Is it a problem with greediness, or did I make a mistake in some other way?

Comment: A Perl regex doesn't have to match the entire string, so you don't need the .*$ at the end.

Comment: instead of just having an empty space i recommend putting \s. it's clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the regex before `[0-9]` is non-greedy, it will match as short a string as possible.

It might be better to constrain your matches by specifying what you want to include, i.e. use something like `[^;0-9]*` instead of `.*?` to match a sequence which should not include semicolons or numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't match the second hour because `.*?` is non-greedy: it *must* take the shortest match. Since everything after the `(lecture|laboratory)` is optional, the shortest possible match is that `.*?` matches nothing, `([0-9])?` also matches nothing, and the `.*` matches everything.

You can change it to be like this:

```
/^(.*)\; *([0-9]).*?(lecture|laboratory)(.*?([0-9]))?.*$/
```

Note that the optional part is now `(.*?([0-9]))?`, i.e. the first `.*?` is paired with a *mandatory* `[0-9]`. This means the `.*?` is only used if there is a second digit to use it with.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the second `.*?` always matches the empty string. Because of the `?` it is forced to match as few characters as possible, and the optional `([0-9])?` allows it to match nothing.

To fix this, change `.*?` to match just non-numeric characters, like this

```
/^(.*)\; ([0-9]).*?(lecture|laboratory)[^0-9]*([0-9]*)/
```

Also, changing `([0-9])?` to `([0-9]*)` will set $4 to an empty string if there is no second hours figure, instead of leaving it undefined.